# Is there a root word for -scendo?

Tags: etymology

There are various words that involve the stem -scendo. For example:

- ascendo
- inscendo
- conscendo
- descendo
- escendo
- transcendo

However, there is no root word that I can find. Scendo itself does not seem to be a word. Is there some root word for these combination words?

Comment: You left out 'crescendo' and 'decrescendo,'  thus offending all musicians :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft BAM bah BAAAAHHHHMMM (ominous horn blast)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rather than *scendo*, the word you're looking for is *[scando](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=scando&la=la#lexicon)*, for which De Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary* has the following:

[image]